# Should we rename the "conflict-aversion" tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The tag [conflict-aversion](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-aversion) is badly named. Aversion is a strong dislike or disinclination. A person can be conflict-averse. The description for this tag says it's more likely to be about [conflict-avoidance](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-avoidance) - ways to keep conflict from breaking out.

Other words may be better suited, but "conflict-averse" is not the right tag.

Suggestions?

Comment: Note that [to avert](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13719?redirectedFrom=avert#eid) is "*to turn away*," or "*to draw away, withdraw*." So "Conflict Aversion" could be the act of "turning away" a conflict. That being said, [even the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_avoidance) says "avoidance" over "aversion," so I definitely agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely agree that we should rename [conflict-aversion](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-aversion). The current tag wiki lists 2 distinct use cases for this tag.

- Avoiding getting pulled into an existing conflict
- Avoiding a potential conflict that has not happened yet

These two use cases, while similar, are distinct enough in my opinion to warrant having separate tags. I would suggest that we rename the existing tag to [conflict-prevention](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-prevention) and use it to cover the case of avoiding (preventing) a conflict from happening. Additionally, we should create a new tag called [conflict-avoidance](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-avoidance) to cover the use case of staying out of an existing conflict.

In light of the information in Bryan Krause's post, I think that the tag wiki for [conflict-avoidance](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-avoidance) should specifically call out that it is not referring to the psychological term.

Answer (score 1):

"[Conflict avoidance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_avoidance)" is a specific term, and it means something completely different to what that "aversion" tag seems to represent.

Although it might be considered an interpersonal skill to know when it could be appropriate to use conflict avoidance, it has a negative connotation of not dealing with the actual problem and is usually thought of as something to overcome.

There is a quote on that Wikipedia page attributed to "Bacal" that I will reproduce here in case it changes:

> Is there a difference between preventing contracting AIDS by the use of appropriate precautions, and avoiding or not seeking treatment if one has contracted it? Of course there is.

"Conflict avoidance" as a term in psychology is referring to the latter case.

In contrast, people seem to be using the [conflict-aversion](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conflict-aversion) tag to mean "I want to resolve an issue without making it into a bigger conflict" - I agree the tag could maybe be renamed, just want to make sure it doesn't get renamed this way!